# OR split function not working in nested way

Tags: python, split

```
case1 = """ do some test
here"""
case2 = """ do some test2
here"""

print(case1.split("some")[1].split('\n|,')[0])
```

neither `\n` nor `,` are working here.

output should be

```
 test
```

but its giving me

```
 test,
here
```

Comment: `split` does not take a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you want to split with a *regex* expression. But that is not how `str.split(..)` works: it splits by a string.

We can use the `re` module to split correctly:

```
import re

print(re.split('\n|,', case1.split("some")[1])[0])
```

This produces:

```
>>> print(re.split('\n|,', case1.split("some")[1])[0])
 test
>>>
```